# Do all backend frameworks support microservices?

Tags: frameworks, microservices, backend

Well I need to develop a web application that has to include microservices and that is going to be deployed on the cloud. And i'm quite lost in choosing the framework to use cuz i'm still not very familiar.
Any help in this matter  would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Microservices are a high-level architectural pattern.

You can implement a microservice in any language or framework (though some frameworks may make some things about the process easier than others).

Comment: What are some of those frameworks that make it easier to implement this kind of architecture?